# Условие php

Tags: php, if, условия

Возможно ли такое условие? Если нет, то напишите как мне будет сделать правильнее

```
if ($mess[im] AND $userinfo[id] == $_GET[im] AND $mess[senderID]) {
echo "Переписка";
} else {
echo "Ошибка...";
}
```

Comment: Удали эту тему (дубликат)

Comment: Это не дубликат. Это отдельная тема, здесь я спрашиваю на счет скрипта, а там я спрашиваю на счет всего

Comment: Объясните человекопонятным языком что вы хотите проверить в условии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы так переписал, хотя из вашего контекста ничего не понятно что такое $mess

```
is_array($mess) && $userinfo['id'] == (int) $_GET['im']
```